# showing one tr and hiding the other in same if both have the same class

Tags: php, html

I have a page to get source code from remote site through File Get Contents PHP function. It works well, and gets the code and echoes it perfectly.

The problem is that there are 2 `<tr>` having the class `<tr class="sectiontableentry2">`.

When I try to hide one of them using CSS `display: none;`, then both disappear.

I want to hide one of them only.

N.B: I don't have access to the code itself as I get it from the remote site.

Here is the code that I get:

```
<tbody>
<tr class="sectiontableentry2">
<td width="18"><img title="Flash" src="../images/soft_icons/flash.png" alt="Flash" /></td>
<td width="80"><a>Flash:</a></td>
<td><a href="http://www.bet365.com/EXTRA/?ContentPath=LiveStreaming%252cStreaming&affiliate=365_057149" target="_blank">Link#1</a>  ( Stable, Recommended Stream! ) <a href="http://www.streamhunter.eu/bet365-important-notice.html" onclick="window.open('http://www.streamhunter.eu/bet365-important-notice.html','notice','width=400,height=300');return false;"><img style="vertical-align:text-bottom;" src="http://www.streamhunter.eu/images/info-icon.png" border="0" alt="Important Notice!" title="Important Notice!" /></a></td>
</tr>
</tbody>

<tr class="sectiontableentry2"> 
<td width="18"><img title="Iframe" src="../images/soft_icons/flash.png" alt="Flash" /></td> 
<td width="80"><a>Flash:</a></td>
<td><a href='javascript:openWindow("index1.php?option=com_lsh&view=lsh&event_id=148636&tv_id=929&tid=32666&channel=0&tmpl=component&layout=popup&Itemid=335","730","730")'  >Link#1</a>  (640x360) </td>
</tr>
</tbody>`enter code here`
```

As you can see there are two `<tr>` both having same class. How can hide the 1st one and let the 2nd to show normally?

Comment: The editor really had lots of patience there!

Answer (score 0):

This is difficult, because there must be a whole lot more HTML not includeded, however if there are only ever two instances of the .sectiontableentry2 class, the below JQuery code will find the first and hide it.

```
//this will select the first tr with the class .sectiontableentry2
$(".sectiontableentry2").first().hide();
```

Comment: have a look at the code i have added it and i already tried this with no luck

Comment: This is strangely formatted HTML.  The tbody is malformed for sure... Is there anymore HTML to show.  You are asking about hiding the tr using JQuery right?